# Entra en el if y en el else a la vez

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

tengo un pequeño problema con una condición. Y es que entra en el IF y en el ELSE a la vez ¿Que puede ser?

```
                let random = Math.random() * 100;
                let random_r = Math.round(random);

                let nombre_evn = document.getElementById('nombre_evn').value;
                console.log("ANTES DE ENTRAR AL CONDICIONAL -> ", nombre_evn);

                if(nombre_evn.length > 0){
                    // Siempre entra en esta condición Y luego ejecuta el ELSE como si nada. 
                    $.post(url, postData, function(response){
                        if(response == 'event success' && random_r >  4){
                            let timerInterval
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Evento Agregado Correctamente',
                                timer: 2000,
                                icon: 'success',
                                timerProgressBar: false,
                                didOpen: () => {
                                    // Swal.showLoading()
                                    const b = Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('b')
                                    timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                                        // b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                                    }, 100)
                                },
                                willClose: () => {
                                    clearInterval(timerInterval)
                                }
                            });
    
                            
                        }
    
                        if(response == 'event success' && random_r <= 4){
                            Swal.fire({
                                title: 'Evento Agregado Correctamente',
                                width: 600,
                                padding: '3em',
                                color: '#716add',
                                backdrop: `
                                    rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
                                    url("../Public/Img/User/neon-cat-rainbow.gif")
                                    center top
                                    no-repeat
                                `
                            })
                        }

                        console.log("RESPUESTA -> ", response);
                        $('#form-c').trigger('reset');

                        myModal.hide();
                        calendar.refetchEvents();
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log("EN EL IF DEL CONDICIONAL (VACIO) -> ", nombre_evn);
                }
```

La primera vez que se ejecuta esto, funciona correctamente. Pero a partir de la segunda vez que lo hago, empieza a entrar en el IF y en el ELSE a la vez.

Ya he probado obteniendo la información de "nombre_evn" de varias maneras y arroja el mismo resultado. También probé cambiando la forma de expresar el condicional pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: ¿Que hace la función `refetchEvents()` ?  Lo digo porque o bien recarga el javascript o la página de alguna forma y ejecuta de nuevo el condicional con otros datos, o bien quizas lo haga el trigger("reset"), y de alli que te parezca que entra en el if y en el else, lo cual no es posible en una única llamada

Comment: Es una función de FullCalendar que actualiza los eventos.

Comment: ¿Y ese código que has puesto en la pregunta es en respuesta a algun evento o está a nivel raiz del javascript?  Si lo tienes en respuesta a un evento... a cual?

Comment: Espera, me acabas de dar una idea.

Comment: ejem... sigo esperando?  ya me ha salido barba y mi pareja se queja

Comment: jsjsjs, no. Ya lo solucione, tenías razón. En parte el problema se debía a esa función. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: jeej, okok, quizás estaría bien que pusieras una respuesta completa tu mismo para que la comunidad lo sepa y así colaboras mejor en el sitio.  Si te lees [answer] aprenderás a realizarlas correctamente y en 48 horas podras aceptarla tu mismo.